# pentaho PDI(kettle) output not found and input not complete

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

I have a problem with PDI (kettle) when I click on spoon.bat i can't find output in the tab design (version 5.2) also the input contain just one element I can't find the other elements like xml or XLS.
I try with other version but the same problem.

Comment: spoon.bat is to open GUI interface in windows environment, and what is your question actually? I think you don't know what you want to achieve. First go with the basics of PDI tool. It will be proper.

Comment: the problem are solved ,when a click in "spoon.bat " the PDI choose french as language so i don't found Input and output folders but when a change language to english  the problem is solved thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i found solution you should open your PDI than clic in "tools-->option-->Fook&Feel" and change language to english.